# Use % pattern in variable name

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a Makefile that uses the same recipe for several variables. The variables are grouped into several lots which need to be built separately but with the same method.

In the example below, I want to be able to build `output1.txt`, `output2.txt` etc. using the same recipe. The catch is that each of these relies on the corresponding variable `$(target1)`, `$(target2)` etc. I've tried to use the `%` pattern to expand these variables but that didn't work because `%` is expanded last.

I have found that I can modify variable calls using recursive variables, eg. `$($(subst 0,$(N),target0))`. However, this cannot be done unless the number is already known.

Is there a simple way to do this?

```
target1:=a_5_2 a_3_5 a_6_2 a_0_0 a_9_1
target2:=a_2_2 a_1_3 a_5_9 a_2_7 a_3_6
target3:=a_2_3 a_6_5 a_9_0 a_3_4 a_3_9
target4:=a_7_8 a_8_2 a_4_8 a_7_1 a_0_7

output%.txt: $($(subst 0,%,target0))
    cat $^ > $@  # do some actual stuff here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

output%.txt: $$(target$$*)
        ...
```

Of course, you could also just change the variables to be prerequisite settings instead; it's about the same amount of typing:

```
output1.txt : a_5_2 a_3_5 a_6_2 a_0_0 a_9_1
output2.txt : a_2_2 a_1_3 a_5_9 a_2_7 a_3_6
output3.txt : a_2_3 a_6_5 a_9_0 a_3_4 a_3_9
output4.txt : a_7_8 a_8_2 a_4_8 a_7_1 a_0_7

output%.txt:
        cat $^ > $@  # do some actual stuff here
```